# AngularJS - How to preselect value in select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, selected

i have array of available select items:

```
// Default available date formats
        $scope.dateformats = [
            {
                code: 'YY.MM.DD',
                name: 'YY.MM.DD'
            },
            {
                code: 'DD.MM.YY',
                name: 'DD.MM.YY'
            }
        ];
```

And I'm trying to default preselected value like this:

```
$scope.actualDateformat = $scope.dateformats[0].code;
```

```
<select ng-options="dateformat.name for dateformat in dateformats" ng-model="actualDateformat" ng-change="changeDateFormat(dateformat)">
   <option style="display:none" value="">{{actualDateformat}}</option>
</select>
```

Problem is, that "preselected" value appears in list as first option tag>

```
<option style="display:none" value="">{{actualDateformat}}</option>
```

After select of any from two  remaining dynamically added items is text in first option appended with text (and value) of the selected item.

How can in solve it please?

I would like to have result like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="YY.MM.DD">YY.MM.DD</option>
  <option value="DD.MM.YY" selected>DD.MM.YY</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Answer (score 2):

Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/SdkpD/9/)

Your problem is you are selecting entire object not code field of that object.

```
dateformat.name for dateformat in dateFormats
    label  : dateformat.name 
    object : dateformat

dateformat.code as dateformat.name for dateformat in dateformats
    label  : dateformat.name
    object : dateformat.code
```

Also I don't understand the need of `option` with`display:none`.

You can select `dateformat.code` like this.

```
<select ng-options="dateformat.code as dateformat.name for dateformat in dateformats" ng-model="actualDateformat" ng-change="changeDateFormat(dateformat)">
</select>
```

Comment: So? When you are writing here i was busy with jsfiddle. And i didn't want to waste my time just for another answer being showed up. I think you are aware of i didn't copy your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<select ng-options="dateformat.name for dateformat in dateformats"
        ng-model="actualDateformat" ng-change="changeDateFormat(dateformat)">
    <option style="display:none" value="">{{actualDateformat}}</option>
</select>
```

To:

```
<select ng-options="dateformat.code as dateformat.name for dateformat in dateformats"
        ng-model="actualDateformat" ng-change="changeDateFormat(dateformat)">
</select>
```

This way, the select should recognize the item where the `dateformat.code` matches `actualDateformat`.

[This blog has some good examples](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/19/using-ngoptions-in-angularjs.aspx) about `ng-options`.

To give you an example:

Assume:

```
$scope.array = [
    { key: 1, value: 'Display text 1!' },
    { key: 2, value: 'Display text 2!' },
    { key: 3, value: 'Display text 3!' }
]
```

Then, using the following options:

```
<select ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in array" ng-model="result">
```

Would result in:

```
<select ...>
    <option value="1">Display text 1!</option>
    <option value="2">Display text 2!</option>
    <option value="3">Display text 3!</option>
</select>
```

`$scope.result` would be set to these option elements' `value` attribute.
If you initialize `$scope.result` as `2`, `"Display text 2!"` should be selected.

Comment: I like this answer because it gives a good blog post about various options as well